# Enviar formulário POST com python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Estou desenvolvendo uma API no meu trabalho, e preciso desenvolver algo no python2 que envia um formulário para o servidor através do POST, vi algumas perguntas aqui no fórum e não consegui encontrar nada que funcionasse ... Preciso do comunidade para me ajudar!

Bem, eu estou usando esse código para entender a lógica e passar para o programador sênior do projeto:

```
import json
import urllib2

data = {
    'id' : 1, 'number': 556291406183, 'message' : 'Hello'
}

req = urllib2.Request('http://lsweb.net.br/gabriel.php')
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')

response = urllib2.urlopen(req, json.dumps(data))
```

Mas não estou obtendo resultados com este código, por isso não envia nada ao servidor. A intenção era enviar para a página do servidor em POST e POST para ler em PHP. AJUDE-ME

Comment: Amigo, aqui é **SOpt** favor traduza sua pergunta! Vejo que já tem um tempo que você é cadastrado na comunidade, então recomendo você a fazer o [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Instale a biblioteca requests pip3 install requests urllib3 --upgrade

import requests
payload = {'username': 'meuusername123', 'password': 'senha1234'} #1

resposta = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/formulario-post", data=payload) #2
```

# 1 Após detectar os campos do código HTML que precisam ser preenchidos, digamos que fosse um formulário de login com usuário e senha, agrupa-se os dados para usa-los na requisição POST

#2 Usa-se o método post do modulo requests para enviar os dados do formulário. Onde você deverá saber através de uma análise básica do código qual url enviar o método POST.

#### Um exemplo real com o website pastebin.com (Enviando dados de login)

URL onde está contido o formulário: https://pastebin.com/login
Valores das TAGs contidas do formulário:

```
Campo de usuário: user_name
Campo de senha: user_password
URL para envio do formulário: /login.php # onde completaremos do o domínio pastebin.com
```

Ficaria dessa forma:

```
import requests
payload = {'user_name': 'meulogin', 'user_password': 'minhasenha123'}
resposta = requests.post("https://pastebin.com/login.php", data=payload)
#print(resposta.text)
```

#### Código HTML bruto

```
<form class="login_form" id="myform" method="post" action="/login.php">
...
</form>


<input type="text" name="user_name" maxlength="20" size="20" value="" 
...
</input>

<input type="password" name="user_password" size="20" value="" placeholder="Your 
...
</input>
```